# CSS navigation absolute/fixed positioning issue?

Tags: css, positioning, css-position, absolute

I've been teaching myself CSS, and decided to try and make a site with the knowledge I have thus far. So I decided to make a fixed navigation bar that follows the position of the web browser, and I ran into an issue. For whatever reason, one of the links I added isn't staying inside the nav bar when I change the browser window size. Can someone look at my code? Please ignore sloppiness, as I'm just trying this for the first time.

Here's my HTML. The "secondnavlinks" div id is the one that won't stay within the nav bar:

```
<div id="nav">

<div id="secondnavlinks">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Ambient Bookmarklet</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<div id="class1">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Saved</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Folders</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="header">
<img src="ambientfollowhead.gif" alt="ambientfollow" width="160" height="35" />
</div>



</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#nav {
position: fixed;
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
top:-1px;
left:109px;
width:85%;
height: 46px;
background-color: white;
z-index: !important 99;
}
```

(Skipped over the "class1" div)

```
#secondnavlinks ul {
position: absolute;
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
}



#secondnavlinks ul li {
display: inline;
text-align: center;
float: left;
font-family: klavika-light;
list-style-type: none;
position: absolute;
left: 950px;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#secondnavlinks ul li > a {
text-decoration: none;
color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first this seemed like it may be the positioning inside of the fixed element.  After looking into this a little bit, I think I've found the culprit...  It seems like your problem is the 'left: 950px;'  - This value won't be browser independant and will vary the results / pop out the element with certain widths.

Like *Libin* mentioned, you want to be looking into Fluid Layout design using relational values instead of fixed values.  So when you rescale your browser everything is set correctly.

Start looking into Media Queries & the use of relational values such as % and Ems.

Here's a useful resource for converting px values to ems etc: http://pxtoem.com/

Also if you want to go through tutorials / courses on the subject, I've included a couple of links below that have helped me in the past:

- http://www.codeschool.com/courses/journey-into-mobile ( Check out the free first lesson )
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-a-crash-course-in-css-media-queries/
- http://www.css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Also, - Here's the proof that using absolute & relative won't pop normally inside the fixed nav bar:  http://jsfiddle.net/JQT7u/2/

Good Luck!

Comment: Yup, you're spot on about the problem I'm having. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Woke up this morning after a night of stress, looked at the resources you linked me to, and fixed the problem! Thanks a million!!

Comment: Late reply, but You're Welcome Tom!  : )

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make a fixed navigation bar that follows the position of the web browser, you should use `%` values instead of `px` values.

[**Check this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/w69FM/)

In that demo, I had changed the values to %, removed some position absolute etc.

Hope this is what you are trying.

Comment: The problem is that when you resize the browser window, the #secondnavlinks div doesn't stay inside the navigation bar -- it gets cut off from the right. I've tested out fixed scrolling and that works fine, but I don't know why the #secondnavlinks won't stay inside of the bar itself. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/aeFx3/1/)

Do you want like this?

It is not clear from your question how the design should be.

BTW, the links were coming out because you were giving the inside div's `position:absolute`. So the links were losing relation with the main div `Nav`.

If you want to know more about working of positioning in CSS then go through this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position).